# Number theory question(different scales)

Tags: number-theory

Write the down this number in (s+1)-number system: 1+22+333+4444+ssss...s.
What is the remainder when you divise this number with (s-1)?

I tried and I think it is (s-2), can't really prove why.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the numbers are $\,s+1\,$ and $\,s-1?\,$ So when $\,s=9\,$ you want to know $\,1+22+333+\cdots+ 999999999\ {\rm mod}\ 8?\ \ $

Comment: @Atvin. Your solution $s-2$ is true iff $s=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sum can be written as
$$x=\sum_{k=1}^{s}\sum_{p=1}^kk(s+1)^{p-1}=-\frac{(1+s)(-2+s^3-2(1+s)^s(-1+s^2))}{2s^3}$$
Now you have $2$ cases:
When $s=2k,k\in\mathbb{N}$ after a computation you will get
$$x\equiv1\mod{s-1}$$
When $s=2k-1$ you will get
$$x\equiv\frac{s+1}{2}\mod s-1$$